# docker registry: https instead of http

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I've just deployed a docker registry.

I'm able to get access to it using:

```
$ curl -I chart-example.local/v2/                                                                                                                         
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 28 Jan 2020 20:10:35 GMT
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

However, when I'm trying to push an local image to it, I'm getting this message:

```
$ docker push chart-example.local/feedly:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
The push refers to repository [chart-example.local/feedly]
Get https://chart-example.local/v2/: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

Why docker is trying to get access using `https` instead of `http`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker uses https by default for security. You can override this setting by modifying your `daemon.json` file with the following content. Do *not* use this setting in production.

```
 {
   "insecure-registries" : ["chart-example.local"]
 }
```

See this link for more information: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/